# ruby assembla api - not taking the auth details provided. - INVALID AUTH error (i used req.basic_auth(key,pwd)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

```
    require 'net/http'
    uri = URI("https://api.assembla.com/v1/activity.json")
    req = Net::HTTP::Get.new(uri.request_uri)
    req.basic_auth "api key", "api secret"

    res = Net::HTTP.start(uri.host, uri.port, :use_ssl => uri.scheme == 'https') { |http|
        http.request(req)
    }

    puts res.body
```

Output :

```
 {"error":"invalid_auth","error_description":"Please provide authentication data (API key/secret pair or a valid access token)"}
```

Also, from the activity api, we can add params like from, to, space_id . But, getting proper result only when single param is used. When I want to get result for a particular day, i need to use both from and to , i used like this : "url?from=frmdate&to=todate", but not getting proper output as per params.(tried this with curl , but with ruby not working at all as i am unable to send auth data properly).

Answer (score 2):

```
   req.basic_auth "api key", "api secret"
```

Remove above line and add below lines, the above line is used for authentication as the method name says. :

```
   req.add_field 'X-Api-Key', 'your key'
   req.add_field 'X-Api-Secret', 'your secret'
```

Here, you have to send those keys as headers.

http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/Net/HTTPHeader.html